# Fastest way to loop over K/V pair array and find object with smallest property

Tags: javascript, arrays

**I build a K/V pair array based on some values.**

Here is the structure:

```
var selItemsDimArray = []

selItemsDimArray.push({
    'examinedElem': multiselected[i],
    'x': bb.x,
    'y': bb.y,
    'x2': (bb.x + bb.width),
    'y2': (bb.y + bb.height),
    'height': bb.height,
    'width': bb.width
});
```

I want to log the `examinedElem` that has the lowest `x` property (which is a float number).

Is there something better I could do other than a FOR/IN?

I am aware that I can use a FOR/IN loop to iterate over the pairs. What would be the most efficient way to do it if only a FOR/IN can do this?

Comment: What makes you optimizing this particular part of your code? Is the `for-in` JS engine implementation proven to be "slow"? Does profiling points to the `for-in` as the slowest part that must be optimized?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Keep track of the lowest detected `x` while filling the array and its accompanying element. No faster way than that.

Comment: Why are you *looping over the k/v pairs*?  Aren't you looping over the *array*, and comparing the x property?  Not the "fastest", but would `selItemsDimArray.sort(function(a,b) { return a.x-b.x; });` work???

Comment: meh - the question is not whether the `FOR/IN` is slow - I'm looking for clever ways to keep track of the smallest property `x` *using* a `FOR/IN` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something better I could do other than a FOR/IN?

Absolutely. `for...in` loops are a bad way of iterating arrays.

Instead, you could use ES5 [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
selItemsDimArray.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.x > curr.x ? curr : prev;
}).examinedElem;
```

It's cool and clear, but since a function must be called at each iteration, a `for` loop is probably faster:

```
var minNum = Infinity, minObj;
for(var i=0; i<selItemsDimArray.length; ++i) {
    if(selItemsDimArray[i].x < minNum) {
        minNum = selItemsDimArray[i].x;
        minObj = selItemsDimArray[i].examinedElem;
    }
}
```

Comment: If "faster" means *programmer time*, then your `reduce`, or my `sort`  (in a comment above), are "fastest".  :-)

Comment: @user949300—maybe, maybe not. Have you factored in ongoing maintenance and rework for changing requirements into that? ;-) Since every member must be visited, there are probably other "fast" solutions based on *forEach*, *map* and *Math.min*.